# How to update Django model's pre-existing record during creation of a new one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In Django, is there a way to update an **existing** record while **creating a new one** with FK relationship to the same parent object.

To elaborate, the scenario will be:

1. Parent model **A** has a child model **B**.
2. New records are added in model **B** for each instance of **A**
3. On **Save**, before the new record is added in **B**, a Boolean field in the previous record is set to `True`.

**The update of the older record will happen along with creation of new record.**

> If one were to fall back on legacy VB workflow, a dataset will have
>   been created for all values of **B** for an instance (PK) of **A** --> Sort (asc) the dataset on PK of **B** --> Goto the last
>   record of the dataset --> Change the boolean value of the hit --> Add a new record.

**How does one approach this scenario in Django?**

## Edit

### FREIGHT TABLES:

```
class Freight(models.Model):
    frt_doc_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Frt Doc Num')
    frt_doc_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, default='RF', ...)
    create_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, ...) 
    mat_group = models.ForeignKey(MaterialGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    RecvPlant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, related_name='receiving_plant', on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    DispPlant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, related_name='dispatching_plant', on_delete=models.CASCADE,...)
    conversion_factor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=4, ...)


class FreightItems(models.Model):
    freight_item = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Line Item Number')
    freight_item_header = models.ForeignKey(Freight, related_name='frt_docs', on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    freight_item_num = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=10, null=True, ...)
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='From date')
    to_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='To date')
    freight_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=0.00, ...)
    frt_rate_past = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Prev.Rate')
```

### Logic for creating records

A **freight document** (header) can be created for combination of these three fields: 1. `mat_group`, 2. `RecvPlant`, 3. `DispPlant`.

There will always be one document for each such combination (of three fields as stated above). The **rates** are added to the table "**FreightItems**" which can change from time-to-time (generally every 15 days). So when a new rate is added (basically in update mode of the particular **freight document**), the last valid rate must be made "**invalid**" by making boolean field `frt_rate_past` set to `True`.

Creation (adding) of a new rate MUST happen simultaneously with setting the old rate "**invalid**" (**boolean field** `frt_rate_past` set to `True`), **in order to ensure that old rates are not picked up**.

### views.py

```
class FreightChangeView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "freight_change.html"
    model = Freight
    form_class = FreightForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('freights_list')

    def clean_status(self):
        return self.instance.status

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        data = super(FreightChangeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['freightitems'] = UpdateFreightFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['freightitems'] = UpdateFreightFormset()
        return data


    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        freightitems = context['freightitems']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if freightitems.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save()                
                freightitems.instance = self.object
                freightitems.save()
#                return redirect('freights_list')

            else:
                context.update({'freightitems': freightitems})
                return self.render_to_response(context)
        return super(FreightChangeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one query, but you can do it in a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly).

```
from django.db import transaction

def viewfunc(request):
    with transaction.atomic():
        # Before the new records are added in B, a Boolean field is set to True.
        # New records are added in model B for each instance of A
```

Comment: How do I get the row with with the boolean `False` in the first step? I have updated my post with code. Shall be most grateful for a reply pls.

Comment: Why not use a datetime field and order it by most recently created rather than using a boolean field? Or have an additional ForeignKey to the correct rate instance?

Comment: Many of the inputs for changes in rates/prices come from external agencies so the creation is many a time after the effective dates. So the first suggestion will not work. I did not get the 2nd suggestion, pls clarify. If I mark the boolean field manually, the job is done but then data integrity may be suspect.

Comment: **PS.** The **boolean** is intended to be used for **preventing a particular rate** from being picked up for downstream docs creation.

Comment: Ok. I meant for the record that's marked as True, you'd have a reference to it via a foreign key field on `Freight`. Like `Freight.active_freight_item`. That way it's only possible to have one active item. Anyway, you can do a filter for any other FreightItems instances that are set to true and update them to false via `filter(field=True).update(field=False)`, then create the new instance with `field=True`.

Comment: Apropos **Anyway, you can do a filter for any other FreightItems instances...** - sorry, but if I were able to mark a field `False`, would I be not able to set the **bool** field `frt_rate_past` as `True` for whichever line item it is `False`? Pls guide me to a query which I may call before a **new** line item (i.e. Freight Item) is created. As I am already referencing the header table `id`, so my query would be something like get all those (in fact under normal circumstances there would be only one) **Freight LIneitems** (for the `id`) where `frt_rate_past` is `False`. And then set it `True`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to write that query for you. It may help you to install ipython and django-extensions to use `python manage.py shell_plus` to play around with the querysets and filters to see what is all possible and what filter you need to meet your requirements and constraints. Once you have those queries, putting them within the context manager I've laid out in my answer will cause all the queries to be run within a transaction at the database level. If you need future help on something unrelated to the transactions, please open a new question.